# How to track an event that is defined using multiple variables?

Tags: google-analytics

An app that lists events relative to user location, e.g. If user opens the app in Paris, France, it will say that there is Bolshoi Ballet event that is playing today 12:00. When user clicks on the showtime, he is taken to an external website that handles booking.

I am interested in two events:

User clicked on the event:

- Event name (in this example [ite], "screening-view").
- `event` variable associated with the screening (ite., "Bolshoi Ballet").
- `date` variable associated with the screening.
- `time` variable associated with the screening (ite., 12:00).
- `location` (country) variable associated with the screening (ite., Paris).
- `vendor` variable associated with the screening (ite., whatever external website handles booking).

User viewed event:

- Event name (in this example [ite], "screening-book").
- `event` variable associated with the screening (ite., "Bolshoi Ballet").
- `date` variable associated with the screening.
- `time` variable associated with the screening (ite., 12:00).
- `location` (country) variable associated with the screening (ite., Paris).
- `vendor` variable associated with the screening (ite., whatever external website handles booking).

I have looked into different options how to approach this requirement and the closest that I can see is using [analytics.js events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events). However, it allows to register only one value (number) associated with the event:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', value);
```

From what I can tell, this cannot be used to visualise events (e.g. how many events have been viewed today) and analyse data (e.g. how many events have been "booked" where event is "Bolshoi Ballet" and country is "France").

Note, all variables (including country) are associated with event in this example, not derived values (e.g. not user country based on their IP).

Answer (score 2):

Actually the event allows you to associate four values, since category, action and label can and should be utilized, too.

For anything else you have to set up [custom dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets). First you have to create them in the properties setting in you GA admin panel (under "custom definitions", and you probably want to go for hit scope). Then you can pass values in your event tracking calls. You have to pass them into the configuration object of the event tracking call (as opposed to set them via the set method) to make sure they are only associated with that specific event and not with all hits on that website. You do not address custom dimensons by the name you gave them in the backend (that's for the reports only) but by the string "dimension" followed by the numeric index.

```
ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'event',          
  'eventCategory': 'screening-view',   
  'eventAction': 'Bolshoi Ballet',      
  'eventLabel': '2015/12/12',
  'dimension1': '10pm', // time
  'dimension2': 'Opéra national de Paris', // location
  'dimension3': 'you know, that little ticket stall close to Monmatre' // vendor
});
```

You only have 20 custom dimension per property in the free version of GA. And they won't show up in the standard reports (you can set them as secondary dimension, though), but you can use them in segments, in view filters and most importantly in custom reports.

Comment: If that is the case, maybe it would make sense to use additional analytics service to Google Analytics just for tracking more complex events?

Comment: The combination of GA and custom dimensions is pretty powerful, especially if you're comfortable with custom reports or working with the API (for example you could save your events in a database with a unique key per user, and save the same key as user scoped custom dimension in analytics. You could then join your database entries an GA information to each other by querying the API with your unique IDs as common key). I don't know your complete use case, but GA will take you a long way so I'd recommend to use everything Google offers before looking at systems that incur fees,

Comment: Actually, what you have described is specifically against GA terms of service and would result in immediate termination of your data suppose if G found out somehow. Probably a bad example. Nonetheless, limits and caveats discourage me to experiment with GA for event tracking. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#Limits For my specific needs, I have chosen keen.io. As others have mentioned, Mixpanel.com, Kilometer.io or Kissmetrics are viable alternatives too.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas you are wrong, what I have described is actually recommended practice by Google (see e.g. Google Analytics evangelsit Cutroni here: http://cutroni.com/blog/2007/10/29/integrating-google-analytics-with-a-crm/ and that's not even new advice). You must not store data that identifes a client within analytics, but you can integrate data via a common key with your backoffice (as long as that key does not identify the user by itself). User data imports wouldn't even work if this was not allowed.

Comment: "unique key per user" is by definition storing data that identifies user itself. What am I am missing? Do mean to say storing a random but unique value per user that could not be used to identify user if data was associated with your database? The latter is not possible.

Comment: I don't know if your are playing silly buggers with me. The party that must not identify the user is Google. You are actually allowed to know the identity of the people you sell tickets to or you would not be able to do so. So as long as you can resolve the key but Google can't you are okay by their TOS:

Comment: I was not. I actually did not know that Google allows that. The opposite, I was under the impression that you are not allowed to collect data in a way that would enable tracking user behaviour cross different sessions, devices, etc. Though I can see that I am definitely wrong about it, https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123663. User ID feature is developed specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Btw. I apologize for "silly buggers" (not a native speaker and I guess that phrase is a bit more offensive than I  thought).

Comment: Assuming that you thought that I have good understanding of who can and who cannot be able to identify user and persisted to ask questions I did, "play silly buggers" is an appropriate idiom, http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+silly+buggers.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to handle this is by using event based analytics tool such as: [Mixpanel.com](http://mixpanel.com) , [Kilometer.io](http://kilometer.io) or Kissmetrics.

Tacking an event(with an array of key:value metadata) is exactly what those tools were designed to do.